# Algorithm to loop an array, make comparison and save data

Tags: arrays, algorithm, coldfusion, cfml

I´m having problems building and algorithm to do the following:

I want to loop over an array that contains all versions tags from a Gitlab project, like this:

```
versions = [
    {
        "name": "2.0.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "2.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.14"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.13"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.12"
    }, 
    ...
]
```

And I want to compare these tags through a gitlap endpoint and save the information retreived.

The comparison needs to be done by two tags, so for cover all the tags will need to be done as follows:

```
Compare the first value of the array "2.0.1" with the second one "2.0.0" 
and Save the data retreived into the first array element "2.0.1".

Compare the second value of the array "2.0.0" with the third one "1.0.14" 
and Save the data retreived into the second array element "2.0.0".

Compare the third value of the array "1.0.14" with the fourth one "1.0.13" 
and Save the data retreived into the third array element "1.0.14".

Compare the fourth value of the array "1.0.13" with the fifth one "1.0.12" 
and Save the data retreived into the third fourth array element "1.0.13".

etc.
```

So I understand that it will be something similar to this:

```
var versions = [ {"name": "2.0.1"}, {"name": "2.0.0"}, {"name": "1.0.14"}, {"name": "1.0.13"}, {"name": "1.0.12"}, ... ];

for( var version in versions){

    var new_tag = ...
    var old_tag = ...
    var diference = compare(old_tag, new_tag);
    
    //and save the difference into the versions old_tag index
    
}
```

**This is the result I expect to have:**

```
var versions = [
    {
        "name": "2.0.1",
        "difference": "difference retreived comparing 2.0.1 and 2.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "2.0.0",
        "difference": "difference retreived comparing 2.0.0 and 1.0.14"     
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.14",
        "difference": "difference retreived comparing 1.0.14 and 1.0.13"        
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.13",
        "difference": "difference retreived comparing 1.0.13 and 1.0.12"        
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.12",
        "difference": "difference retreived comparing 1.0.12 and ..."       
    }, 
    ...
]
```

Is not a must to save it in the versions array, it can be saved in a new created array but the information has to be like that.

Can someone help to finisht this algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you're running into? This seems like a straightforward task

Comment: I think `compare` is a built-in cf function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some mucking about [here](https://trycf.com/gist/8c2376a0128a983638eadbb3eb727227/acf2021?theme=monokai), and came up with the following code.

```
<cfscript>
versions = [
    {
        "name": "2.0.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "2.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "2.0.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.14"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.13"
    },
    {
        "name": "1.0.12"
    }
];
for (version in versions) {
position = arrayfind(versions, version);
if (position < arraylen(versions)) {
if (versions[position].name is not versions[position + 1].name) {

writedump(position & " " & versions[position].name & " is not " & versions[position + 1].name);
}
else {
writedump(position & " " & versions[position].name & " is the same as " & versions[position + 1].name);
}
}
}
</cfscript>
```

You will want to use the `StructInsert` function to modify your data.  I'll leave that in your capable hands.

Comment: Thanks! It was not exaclty what I asked for but you help me complete the task! Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @PabloPortillo For future readers, can you please give a little more info on what the problem was that you were trying to solve?

Comment: @Shawn Of course, I will try. The task was by itself a bit confusing to be honest. I tried to be as clear as possible and give all the info I had but even like that I know sounds confusing. Thanks for your message.

Comment: @PabloPortillo What info are you trying to compare? Can you provide an example? Also, I think these "name" tags should be sorted in the proper order to make sure you're comparing the right things.